# MS Access shared on SharePoint with multiple users and linked tables

Tags: database, ms-access, sharepoint, split

I have an Access Database (2010) that uses a linked table from a SharePoint (2013) list of names. It does not edit the information on the SharePoint list, but rather pulls the names from SP to populate the name field in the new records in Access. The user then can add in the additional information stored in the Access DB (in this case, it is somewhat of a "report card" form that allows the teacher to input student's grades).

This DB is stored on a SharePoint site. When teachers try to use it, they are prompted to save the DB locally and then "Save to SharePoint" when they are done. The problem is that if two teachers are using it at the same time and one saves to SP after the other, the latter teacher will overwrite all the changes that the former teacher made.

I've done some research and it seems that "splitting" the Access DB might work to allow teachers to simultaneously edit (only a maximum of 6 users will be editing at the same time). But I have not tried this method before. Will splitting into front-end and back-end affect the linked table of names that is taken from a SharePoint list? What is the best way to allow simultaneous edits?

Answer (score 0):

Briana,
what version of SharePoint do you have? Newer versions allow publishing Access DB as a website (WEB compatible database). You have to install "access services" in SharePoint.

The second variant would be splitting the ACCESS DB into front and back end. Back-end would be your SharePoint lists as tables. Front-end would be your Access application permanently saved on each teacher's desktop.

if your current Access application uses SharePoint List as tables then you don't have to worry about overwriting the database because the data would be always the same just the layout changes each teacher is customizing would affect all others layout.

The best way would be splitting the Access application giving each teacher their own login and their own version and of course all tables are linkedTabled from SharePoint list.